# React is rendering [object object] rather than the JSX in UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My React code is rendering [object object] rather than the JSX in UI,

My Code -

```
const renderIntended = (column, data, type, row) => {
            let value = data;
            const treeHtml = `<div class="tree-link" style='font-size: 14px; cursor: pointer; color: #565659;'>
                Click More + ${treeSideBar(value)}
             </div>`;

            if (isNull(data)) {
                value = "-";
            } else if (row.op != "replace") {
                const parsable = isParsable(data);
                if (parsable) {
                    // value = "{ ; }";
                    value = treeHtml;
                }
            }
            return `${value}`;
        };

        const treeSideBar = (value) => {
            return <div><TreeSideBar treeData={value}/></div>
            // return value;
        }
```

I have one renderIntended function which renders table column data and format in some display.
But what I am facing is If I return treeHtml without the  components it shows the text but when it its included it show Click More + [object Object]

[image]

I am unable to render <TreeSideBar inside this.

React is rendering [object object] rather than the JSX in UI. Please guide me.

PS:  If I show my <TreeSideBar outside the table it works fine only inside table column it's showing as [object Object].

Comment: Why don't you directly call `<TreeSideBar />` in your `treeHtml ` value ? `const treeHtml = <div>Click More <TreeSideBar treeDate={value}/></div>`

Comment: @Weedoze still it show [Object Object]

Comment: Then it is because you are not calling `renderIntended` inside a component

Comment: @Weedoze I am calling inside that and it's working, Only thing is when I return some component it show [Object Object]

Answer (score 1):

JSX returns something called a render factory

so this

```
<div />
```

becomes

```
React.createElement("div")
```

which in return will give you a `object` with some react specific props.
That's why you see [object object].

You cannot simply render JSX or a React element into string, as you are trying to do.

Your options might be rendering as documented within the React renderer or use something like `ReactDOM.renderToString`

Comment: You meant to say, `return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <TreeSideBar treeData={value}/>
   )` I should use like this ?

Comment: I have added `return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <TreeSideBar treeData={value}/>
   )` it renders some element instead of [object object] but it's not same what i want.. some element or html are not coming fine